# How to send message in Flutter to a channel websocket?

Tags: flutter, message, send, channel

I write an app flutter connect websocket. I use IOWebsocketChanel:
My code Flutter:

```
widget.channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://10.2.2.89:8080/socket');
```

I connect success.
My code server:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat/message")
public void chatMessage(String message) {
  simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/chat", message);
}
```

But my problem:
How i send message from flutter app to path "/chat/message"? What IOWebsocketChanel function?
I read docs and example. They use chanel.sink.add(message). But It not send message to path "/chat/message"
Please help me.

Comment: your question is confusing, but i guess we are having the same issue.........please try using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stomp, it will help you connect to your spring websocket

Comment: Thanks. But I used socketio on backend and plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/socket_flutter_plugin. I resolved it.

Comment: @HaiNguyen, good thing that you're able to resolve it. It would be nice if you could post the detailed answer for us to be able to understand the issue well.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [official guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets) on sending messages using websockets on Flutter. I recommend using [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) package for this use case.